# pysimplegui syntax error with icon commands

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Alright so im messing around with a tutorial i followed, and now im trying to get an icon on it (not part of the tut) i've gone through what documentation on it i could find, and followed some different tutorials on how to, whenever i run the code i get

```
C:\Users\kamron\Desktop>python filenamehere.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filenamehere.py", line 9, in <module>
    window = sg.Window('Bot', layout, icon)
NameError: name 'icon' is not defined

C:\Users\******\Desktop>python sayoribot.py
  File "filenamehere.py", line 8
    icon=(icon='C:\\Users\\******\\Desktop\\bot_icon.ico')
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and here's the code im using to try and get an icon for my program (which is a whole other issue i have, but hopefully if i figure out my error here i can get it)

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
sg.theme('BlueMono')
set_icon =(icon='C:\\Users\\******\\Desktop\\bot_icon.ico')
layout =[[sg.Text('How can i help?'), sg.InputText()],[sg.Button(' Ok '), sg.Button('Quit')]]
window = sg.Window('Bot', layout, icon)
```

i've messed around with placement of the =, but i dont understand the issue. i did try

```
set_icon(icon='C:\\Users\\******\\Desktop\\bot_icon.ico')
```

it came up with another syntax error. any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

(No its not exactly a bot im working on its just name placeholders lol.)

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
set_icon =(icon='C:\\Users\\******\\Desktop\\bot_icon.ico')
```

Is trying to assign a value to `set_icon`. However, inside that assignment you have *another* assignment — to `icon`. This is not allowed in Python<sup>1</sup>.

Your attempted fix is better:

```
set_icon(icon='C:\\Users\\******\\Desktop\\bot_icon.ico')
```

This is the correct syntax for calling a function named `set_icon` passing a single named argument. However, you probably haven’t defined `set_icon`. If you want to use the PySimpleGUI function of that name, you need to specify an object to call it on (i.e. `window`). But you don’t need to do so since you are *passing* the icon in its constructor. All you have to do is actually *define* that icon by assigning a variable.

In other words: remove the `set_icon` call — *just* leave the variable assignment:

```
icon='C:\\Users\\******\\Desktop\\bot_icon.ico'
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Specifically, it requires using the “walrus operator”, `:=`</sub>